# Can we show all the saved cards and use them through stripe in Flutter Web. If yes, then How?

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, flutter-stripe

Can we show all the saved cards for respective customers and use them to make payments through Stripe in Flutter Web? If yes, then How?

I tried most of the things but haven't achieved what I am looking for yet.

I am expecting this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Stripe Flutter web is still [highly experimental](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe#web-experimental) and they seem haven't support that feature (which is available via PaymentSheet in Flutter mobile or any other Stripe mobile SDKs)

Comment: yes and I implemented it with PaymentSheet right now but i am unable to use already saved cards to make payments. Do you have any idea about it, as I tried to pass payment method id also to payment intent in order to get saved card details in PaymentSheet but it is not showing tho @orakaro.

Comment: Do you pass customer id and ephemeral key secret in PaymentSheet?

Comment: yes, i tried but it didn't worked! @orakaro

Comment: Can't say without concrete code. Recommend writing to Stripe Support or chat with their developers on Discord